# Why my Query string is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing problem in query string. Following is my asp code

```
  <asp:Label ID="Lable1" runat="server" Text=""  ></asp:Label>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

C# code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lable1.Text += Request.QueryString["refresh"] ;
    Response.Redirect("QueryString1t.aspx?refresh=" + 1 + "");    
}
```

Up to my knowledge Lable1 text should change on button click every time. Lable1 text should not show any thing  on page load . on button click it should be like for first click 1 for second click 11 and so on..
But it is not showing as my expectation .So tell me please where i am wrong?

Comment: May be you need to replace `Label` with `TextBox`?

Comment: Well, yes, the label _does_ get the extra text, but after that, you immediately redirect the page, so the extra text doesn't get the time to show up. Rethink the order in which you do things.

Comment: @Oybek No, that won't be necessary.

Comment: Can you tell me ,how can i get my desired out put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting after setting label text, wrong approach.

### Try this: -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lable1.Text = Request.QueryString["refresh"];
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("QueryString1t.aspx?refresh=" +
     string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["refresh"]) ? 0 :
      Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["refresh"]) + 1 + "");    
}
```

### OR this: -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lable1.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Lable1.Text) ? "0" :
        (Convert.ToInt32(Lable1.Text) + 1).ToString();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Particularly the fourth and fifth events in the cycle.

If you want the text to be updated as you are looking for there, then you need to put that code in the page load, not the click event handler.

In brief, you have to think of it like this: Every time you do a redirect, you lose viewstate,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

which is the means by which ASP.NET keeps track of your updates to the controls, like in your event handler. So your update is immediately lost.

The next piece of code you will hit is your load event, so *that* is where you need to set the label's text property.

[How do I persist the value of a label through a response.redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/how-do-i-persist-the-value-of-a-label-through-a-response-redirect)